# Page Template for every custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm just new in wordpress, I just wanted to ask if it's a bad practice if I'll create page template for every custom post types?
I mean if I have CPT [custom post type] with different content, like my first CPT has images, my 2nd cpt has image and text, my last CPT, has slider, text and description.

Because I wanted to create page template for every type of CPT's I have. Is it a bad practice? Or are there efficient and effective ways to do such things?

Your answers are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to do that, not only because it's a server load, but also because you'll get crazy if you have an issue. Instead, use conditionals in the same page. You can read about it at [WP Codex: Conditional Tags : Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#is_tax) and then pay attention to the [is_tax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) and [has_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) tags.

This way, you can use is_tag or has_term depending on your approach, like this

```
if( has_term( 'jazz', 'genre' ) ) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Or maybe I can use post_type_exists()?

Comment: no, because it will output the code you echo if post type exists, and you will have the case that post type will exist, but not necessarily use that snippet of code. Just for reference, check the default WP themes to see how index page is built and the conditional and template parts

Comment: But I can't understand how to use it. If my custom type name is features, how will I use that has_term, is_tax? I've created taxonomy for my CPT, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You can use taxonomy to deal with such problem. Use taxonomy to filter contents according to your requirements. Use `register_taxonomy()` to register a taxonomy for CPT.